# Inductive limits

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E_n$ be a family of Banach spaces. Under which conditions imposed on $(E_n)$ can we represent the $\ell_\infty$-sum $(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n)_{\ell_\infty}$ as a complemented subspace of *some* inductive limit of $(E_n)$? I do not require the inductive limits to be Banach spaces.